# Antivirus is blocking my inno setup compiled executable .exe file

Tags: java, jar, inno-setup, antivirus

I am using inno setup compiler to create exe file but antivirus solution is blocking my compiled exe file. what can I do to resolve it in my inno script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not much detail to work with. Which brand antivirus? What does it detect it as? Any specific messages to share?

Comment: It can be hard to do anything in the script. You have 2 possibilities:
1. Add Digital Signature - e.g. Thawte, Symantec, but it costs to buy it
2. You can check your installer on https://www.virustotal.com/pl/ (or other combo pages) and then send your code/installer exe to specific AntiVirus Company, e.g. Symantec, McAfee, Kaspersky Lab and ask them to whitelist your code.

Comment: It is avast antivirus.

Comment: Late comment, but well, since you mentioned Avast...this may help someone out there.

Comment: You will need to use a combo - detecting that your setup is blocked by Avast (or AVG - today owned by the same company so using the same approach) from within Inno, and then have it CyberCaptured and white-listed hours later, before it goes live for your customers. Too many details to list here (I'd answer a new question on this, though), and I'm sorry for being so terse and unhelpful - but it can be done. (I tried all the other suggestions, none worked.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends why the antivirus is blocking your executable.

If it's flagging it as an infection, then your only choice is to report it as a false positive to the antivirus vendor after confirming it's clean with [VirusTotal](http://virustotal.com).

If it's a generic "suspicious file" then you can try adjusting the level in the antivirus or reporting it as before.